# What are baby scissors for?

Tags: tools

We recently bought baby scissors (like shown [here](https://www.google.de/search?q=baby%20scissors&oq=baby%20scissors&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5708j0j4&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc)) and hoped to use it for cutting fingernails. These are not good for that. However, their name is not baby nail scissors so we should not expect them to be good for that purpose.

What are baby scissors good for?

Description on box:
"These baby scissors are made of stainless steel and have blunt tips to prevent injury. Slip-resistant handles ensure a firm grip while cutting. Includes protective cover for save and tidy storage. To clean, we recommend a clean, damp cloth. Do not clean in dishwasher. ..."

Comment: If you want a better answer you probably should include a link to the specific product or a picture of the box.

Comment: if you Google 'baby scissors', you'll get images for children's safety scissors. These are meant for children to learn  cutting/scissor-using skills.  Of course there are also images for 'baby nail scissors'. Brits/Canadians and so on use the word 'baby' as in small. I have  baby toes and baby fingers. In the USA (and probably elsewhere) they use 'little' toe and 'little' finger instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely they're still intended for nail scissors, for example [this one](http://bfb-pharma.com/product/baby-scissor-with-blunt-tips/) does not say "nail" but is definitely for that purpose.

Of course, they could also be oddly labeled child scissors; while a child of the age usually called "baby" usually wouldn't play with any sort of scissors that are not plastic, it's possible that these are really toddler scissors (and thus intended to let toddlers use scissors).  My children both were using metal scissors around 2 years old (with blunted tips).

Comment: We tried them, they did not cut like we expected them to cut. Therefore i wondered.